# Reading data from sdcard in android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I need to read files from sdcards to display on emulator.I've to split text files,image files,video files separately .when i click any file,its contents have to play or display.How could i do that.?Thanks in adv.

Comment: have you tried anything? What does not work? What is the problem? There are tons of examples how to manipulate the external storage.